# How do I upload .git folder to Github repo

Tags: git, github, git-filter-repo

I'm using tool called **git-filter-repo** (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) to rewrite my git history and remove some large binaries in the `.pack` file and reduce the overall repo size.
This makes changes to the local repo, and disconnects a clone from a Github repo.

Now I need to upload the changes in the folder `.git` to Github. Since it's not content and do not appear as uncommitted changes, 1. How can I upload the changes? The instructions page doesn't describe that scenario.

Several instructions on using Github often describe uploading folders or content. 2. Does this apply to the `.git` folder?

Comment: The `.git` directory is where Git stores all the data. The directory containing `.git` is the view of one commit in that data. A remote Git repository is basically nothing *but* the `.git` directory. Your local repository should have changes reflected in its commit history, which you can force push to a remote.

Comment: Note that you might/would need to force-push all branches affexted by the `filter-repo` command.